# How re-execution would be the primary source of fault tolerance?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

In one of the research papers on MapReduce, there is a sentence:

> Our use of a functional model with user specified map and reduce operations allows us to parallelize large computations easily and to use re-execution as the primary mechanism for fault tolerance.

I didn't understand what re-execution actually means and how re-execution can be primary mechanism for fault tolerance?

Comment: Can you please share that research paper url here. Is it the research paper by j dean

Comment: @siddharthajain The url of the research paper is https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give a general answer.

Causes of Faults or failures:

1. Node failure/unreachable
   In other words, this means that all the tasks running in that node failed/gone unreachable.
2. Task failure/unreachable
   The data being processed by all the tasks inside a node will be saved locally and when the node fails or becomes unreachable(to other nodes or the master) then the there is no way to retrieve the data processed so far. So obvious solution is to restart these tasks on the same node or some other nodes(node failure). This makes re-execution the primary mechanism for fault tolerance.

Another analogy for *re-execution for fault tolerance* is redundancy for data loss. Data is duplicated to avoid data loss by storage devices. Similarly, tasks are re-executed to make the applications fault tolerant.